# Wrong networkx predecessors when used inside a function

Tags: python-3.x, function, filter, graph, networkx

I am trying to find the parents of my nodes in the graph `G` but when I use the `predecessor` method inside a function my filtering method returns the wrong answer.

MWE:

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.MultiDiGraph()
G.add_node("Z_1")
G.add_node("Z_0")
G.add_node("X_1")
G.add_edge('X_1','Z_1')
G.add_edge('Z_0','Z_1')
```

Simple function to find nodes at different time-indices:

```
def node_parents(node: str, temporal_index: int = None) -> tuple:
    #  Returns the parents of this node with optional filtering on the time-index.
    if temporal_index:
        # return (*[v for v in  G.predecessors(node) if v.split("_")[1] == str(temporal_index)],)
        return tuple(filter(lambda x: x.endswith(str(temporal_index)), G.predecessors(node)))
    else:
        return tuple(G.predecessors(node))
```

Now then, let's use the function:

```
node_parents("Z_1",0)
>>>('X_1', 'Z_0')
```

Ok. Let's use the `predecessor` method in a filter outside the function:

```
(*[v for v in G.predecessors('Z_1') if v.split("_")[1] == "0"],)
>>>('Z_0',)
```

All I want to do is to filter out, in this example, nodes which are zero-indexed (i.e. strings which have a zero at the end). But for some reason I am getting different answers. Why is this?

Comment: A `temporal_index` of zero evaluates to false. You meant to write `if temporal_index is not None:`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Paul Brodersen the correct way to write this is:

```
def node_parents(node: str, temporal_index: int = None) -> tuple:
    #  Returns the parents of this node with optional filtering on the time-index.
    if temporal_index is not None:
        # return (*[v for v in  G.predecessors(node) if v.split("_")[1] == str(temporal_index)],)
        return tuple(filter(lambda x: x.endswith(str(temporal_index)), G.predecessors(node)))
    else:
        return tuple(G.predecessors(node))
```